# how can I check if a file exists?

Tags: vbscript, wsh

I want to check to see if a file exists and if it does, I want to open it and read the 1st line,

If the file doesn't exist or if the file has no contents then I want to fail silently without letting anyone know that an error occurred.

Comment: Did you search for `vbscript file exists` anywhere?

Comment: @Fionnuala but this *is* the first result from google :D ;)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Start with this:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If (fso.FileExists(path)) Then
   msg = path & " exists."
Else
   msg = path & " doesn't exist."
End If
```

Taken from the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x23stk5t%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is looking a way to watch a specific file to exist in VBS:

```
Function bIsFileDownloaded(strPath, timeout)
  Dim FSO, fileIsDownloaded
  set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  fileIsDownloaded = false
  limit = DateAdd("s", timeout, Now)
  Do While Now < limit
    If FSO.FileExists(strPath) Then : fileIsDownloaded = True : Exit Do : End If
    WScript.Sleep 1000      
  Loop
  Set FSO = Nothing
  bIsFileDownloaded = fileIsDownloaded
End Function
```

Usage:

```
FileName = "C:\test.txt"
fileIsDownloaded = bIsFileDownloaded(FileName, 5) ' keep watching for 5 seconds

If fileIsDownloaded Then
  WScript.Echo Now & " File is Downloaded: " & FileName
Else
  WScript.Echo Now & " Timeout, file not found: " & FileName 
End If
```

Answer (score -3):

an existing folder will FAIL with FileExists

```
Function FileExists(strFileName)
' Check if a file exists - returns True or False
```

**use instead or in addition:**

```
Function FolderExists(strFolderPath)
' Check if a path exists
```

Comment: This answer does not answer the question. It also does not follow the formatting guidelines.