# VB script - search for a file in directory

Tags: vbscript, system-administration

I am trying to write a VB script (having never attempted before) - I need it to search the folder'\file001\source$' - whilst in the folder search for all 'Update.exe'files - If this is done manually, in Windows it takes a long long time! 
I would like all the files that it finds with this name - to be copied into a new folder.

Looking at various help forums I am getting more and more confused.

Below is what I have attempted:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
ShowSubfolders fso.GetFolder("\\file001\source$")
```

'foldername = "\file001\source$"
  'filename   = "Updater.exe"

```
Function ShowSubFolders(Folder)
    For Each Subfolder in Folder.SubFolders
        Wscript.Echo Subfolder.Path
        ShowSubFolders Subfolder
    Next
End Function
```

This is to search through a folder, recursively through the folders sub folders to find all files with this name.

I have also done research into -directory.getfiles. But have no clue if this is the right direction.

As a newbie to VB script, I have researched and attempted to play around with vb script, to get the function I desire. I would be grateful to any help I can get.

Again - my target is to - find all files within the given folder and subfolders with the name update.exe - and then to copy these files found into a new folder. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161739/vbs-how-can-i-check-if-a-file-exists

Comment: A little confused at this link. This is solving a different problem? I do not want to open the file or take the first line

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to check the content of a single folder for the existence of a particular file you can do that like this:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

foldername = "\\file001\source$"
filename   = "Update.exe"

If fso.FileExists(fso.BuildPath(foldername, filename)) Then
  WScript.Echo filename & " exists."
End If
```

If you want to check the subfolders of `foldername` as well, you need to recurse into subfolders with something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14965606/1630171). You can either integrate the check from the above code sample in the loop over the subfolders, or add another loop over the files in the folder:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

CopyUpdater fso.GetFolder("\\file001\source$")

Sub CopyUpdater(fldr)
  For Each f In fldr.Files
    If LCase(f.Name) = "update.exe" Then
      'copy file to somewhere else
    End If
  Next

  For Each sf In fldr.SubFolders
    CopyUpdater sf
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for assistance with searching for a single file - I have posted my update above - I am struggling with check subfolders additionally.

Answer (score 1):

See my question here, i benchmark three languages (vbscript also) which do a subdirectory traversal with full working samples and optimised for the language. [benchmarks: does python have a faster way of walking a network folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13138160/benchmarks-does-python-have-a-faster-way-of-walking-a-network-folder)

Answer (score 0):

Thats a good attempt . Read more on below link and understand things better .

- [Vbscript list all PDF files in folder and subfolders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200028/vbscript-list-all-pdf-files-in-folder-and-subfolders)
- [VBScript to traverse through subdirectories](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ITCG/thread/102ef98d-e815-40f3-9e7a-b28b2b1311c7/)

Answer (score -1):

```
dim sFilename

Dim objDict
Set objDict=CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
sFilename = ""

'root folder path where subfolder exists 
fileLocation="C:\Users\u258251\Desktop\TestSubfolder"

Dim objFSO 'File System Object
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Add all files with specific extention to dictonary 

Call Recurse(fileLocation)



ItemArray = objDict.Items


'Loop through dictonary
For i = 0 To objDict.count -1
    sFilename = sFilename & ItemArray(i) & VBCRLF
Next 

msgbox(sFilename)

'find a specific file by name and return path 
if objDict.Exists("DP103.txt") then 
    msgbox(objDict.Item("DP103.txt")) 
end if

Sub Recurse(strFolderPath)
    Dim objFolder
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strFolderPath)
    Dim objFile
    Dim objSubFolder

    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        If (InStr(objFile.Name, ".") > 0) Then

            'proceed if extention is .txt 
            If (LCase(Mid(objFile.Name, InStrRev(objFile.Name, "."))) = ".txt") Then 
                if objDict.Exists(objFile.Name)=false then 
                'add files and path to dictonary 
                objDict.Add objFile.Name,objfile.Path 
                End if 
            End if 
        End If 
    Next

    For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.SubFolders
        Call Recurse(objSubFolder.Path)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: `objDict.Add objFile.Name,objfile.Path` will fail (i.e. loose files), if you have files with the same name in different folders.

Comment: Ekkehard: sorry earlier formatting was no correct , but its checking "if objDict.Exists(objFile.Name)=false then "  before adding to dictionary

Comment: please try to understand the problem (keys of a dictionary are unique).